# Update AlertDialog fields from AsyncTask on Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have an android mobile application in which there is an AlertDialog. In this dialog, the users enter some data that have to be validated via remote API call. My problem here is that I don't know how to update the opened AlertDialog from the onPostExecute function, since the AlertDialog elements are not visible to the remaining class before it be shown.

I think that somewhere I lost it. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: It's messy. 3k lines Activity :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the AlertDialog as a member variable on the Activity/Fragment. That way it'll be available to the AsyncTask (i'm assuming it is an inner class).